# jquery addClass to all the li:first.selection

Tags: jquery

jquery how to addClass to all the `ul.menu` `li:first.selection`?

demo code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/NkbDY/

I need `menu1` `menu4` `menu7`, all the `first li` in `ul.menu` change font color to red.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('ul.menu li:first-child').addClass('current');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NkbDY/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul.menu').each(function(i,e){
   $('li:first',e).addClass('current');
});
```

Group my `.menu` first, then find the first of each menu.

More concisely, [`first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) also does this:

```
$('ul.menu li:first-child').addClass('current');
```